# Unread inbox badge doesn't disappear after reading message

Tags: bug, ios-app

When new comment on post appears then badge with "1" shows near inbox tab, e.g.:

> [image: inbox1]

After tapping on the message - the comment is shown together with the post (main part of the iOS app screen), but "1" badge didn't disappear. Even after manual refreshing by swiping down inbox messages.

"1" badge has been disappeared only after selecting another tab, e.g. Reputation tab.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)